# Is there an equivalent to "kubectl get crds [name] -o yaml" for normal k8s objects?

Tags: kubernetes

I'd like to be able to look at the definition of a standard k8s object (ex Deployment) which includes all the same definition output as the "kubectl get crds [name] -o yaml" command, but for a  standard k8s object.

"kubectl explain deployment" only provides very basic information.  I'm looking for something like a CRD but for standard k8s objects like a Deployment.  I'm trying to get to the openAPIV3Schema definition of standard objects.

Comment: You can `kubectl explain deployment.spec` to dig into fields, or `kubectl explain --recursive=true deployment`.  Does it specifically need to be OpenAPI schema syntax?

Comment: Ideally yes as I'd like to pull this information into a Crossplane composition.  Oddly, `kubectl explain deployment --output=plaintext-openapiv2` isn't it either